# TVHEADEND crash - too many open files (epoll and tvhpoll)

Tags: crash, root

From time to time my tvh server crashes and it needs to be restarted. In log I noticed this record

```
 tvhpoll: failed to create epoll [Too many open files]
```

I tried to raise the limits and followed this thread

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880557/socket-accept-too-many-open-files

But I don't see any difference. I was wondering if the limits are limited for specific user. For example when I raise them as root if it effects all users or only root. TVheadend is using hts user.

Could you pls help me how to eliminated this problem. I am not expert, probably there are some files still opened and not closed or maybe closed after longer period.

A script maybe could help how to closed all open files?

Comment: Regarding the ulimit. Have a look at this : https://access.redhat.com/solutions/61334. Basically, using * will be valid for all users and @<group name> for the specific group only.

Comment: I tired to use * as well but it didn't seemed to have any effect. Server was rebooted. Btw is it the right limit I am trying to edit?

Comment: Can you post exactly how you edited the config and what you edited. And also what is the output of ulimit -n ?

Comment: this is in /etc/security/limits.conf
     
         * soft     nproc          965535

         * hard     nproc          965535

         * soft     nofile         965535

         * hard     nofile         965535

und ulimit -n 

965535

Comment: just to be sure have you restarted after editing the limits.conf file? Also I found this [post](https://www.tvheadend.org/boards/5/topics/26727). The last post mentions that you may need to edit or override the systemd unit file fo the tvheadend service.

Comment: yes, after every change I restarted system. thanks for the effort. I will try to search info about limit in systemd

Comment: possible solution with **prlimit**. Described below in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

POSSIBLE WORKING SOLUTION:

I have found "light" solution. Those limits didn't effect tvheadend.
When I used this command to find out tvheadend pid

```
 pidof tvheadend
```

than here I could see the limits

```
 cat /proc/PID_OF_TVHEADEND/limits
```

We have to edit this line

```
Max open files      1024           4096            files
```

All I had to do was edit this value

```
  prlimit -n4096:4096 -p PID_OF_TVHEADEND
```

it bassicly set both limit to 4096 (in my case first one was 1024).

One tiny problem is when the service is restarted. The limits are set to its default value.  I have script to find out the pid and automaticly set the limits. It runs in cron every 6th hour which is good because the crash is after around 18 hours of running the service.

The best solution would be to raise this value so when the service restart it stays as it was before the restart.